# Akka actor avoiding mutating state

Tags: scala, akka

I'm pretty new to using Akka actors. Very recently, I read about distributed actors or remote actors (whatever you call it). I have been comfortable so far using state in my Actor and mutate it inside my receive method. Happy days! Now I want to distribute my actor across several JVM's and I already see that my state in my actor could be an issue.

I did read about the become and unbecome and I was just wondering how Akka handles this internally?

With state:

```
class TestActor extends Actor {
  var state = List.empty[String])

  def receive = 
    case Add(elem) => state + elem
    case Contains(elem) => sender() ! state.contains(elem)
  }
}
```

With state removed:

```
class TestActor extends Actor {
  def receive = start(List.empty[String])

  def start(lst: List[String]): Receive = {
    case Add(elem) =>
      context become start(lst+ elem)

    case Contains(elem) =>
      sender() ! lst.contains(elem)
  }
}
```

Where did the state go in the second version with the become example?

Comment: What makes you think mutating state in your actor can be an issue in remote context?

Comment: Say I have a counter that I have in my Actor encapsulated as an instance variable. This Actor is deployed across JVM's. Subsequent messages are processed by one of these Actors. How can I have a unified view on the counter?

Comment: This is the main concern actors and message passing takes care for you. None of the state in the actor are directly accessible to you outside the actor - even within the same JVM. Your original case is perfectly thread safe in multi-JVM case.

Comment: When you say “this Actor is deployed across JVMs” this implies a misunderstanding: each actor is a singleton, only in one place, and it does not matter how you model its state (it will be encapsulated just the same). Having multiple instances of an Actor class makes multiple independent singletons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The state is held by the Akka machinery. There's a stack of `receive` "blocks"
that's mutated every time you call `become` or `unbecome`.

The stack is represented as [an immutable `List` bound to a `var`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/d400598037d1c1766e4eb8ef4cbbaaff04dbe7c1/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorCell.scala#L396).

There are two places where the `List` is replaced:

- [`become`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/d400598037d1c1766e4eb8ef4cbbaaff04dbe7c1/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorCell.scala#L528-L529)
- [`unbecome`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/d400598037d1c1766e4eb8ef4cbbaaff04dbe7c1/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorCell.scala#L536-L541)

Compared to Erlang, Akka couldn't use the execution stack created by a recursive call to encode state, because that means a blocking call. Akka cannot afford a blocking call on any of its threads, so it needs a `var`.

Akka's `receive` blocks **may give** the illusion of recursive calls, but remember, a `receive` block returns a `PartialFunction` which, when called, calls `start`.

Answer (score 5):

Conceptually, the state is on the execution stack. `Receive` is a type alias for a `PartialFunction`. The partial function in the implementation of the `start` method closes over the `lst` parameter. The receive behavior can then be evaluated on demand using parameter values from the execution context.

So the size of `lst` does indeed grow every time the start method is called.

In reference to *leaking memory*, note that by default `become` is unnested so there is no memory leak. Only if you pass `false` for the `discardOld` parameter, allowing for a future `unbecome`, can there be an issue with a memory leak.

Comment: This is a bit inaccurate. 1. `become` doesn't close over anything. 2. `become`'s parameter is not by-name, the `start` method is executed before the `become` call is executed. The by-name illusion is given by the fact that `start` **returns** a `PartialFunction`.

Comment: Right, so the fact that it returns a `PartialFunction` means that the function itself is returned rather than the evaluation of the function. So technically it is is pass-by-value of the function itself (as a value) and not by-name. Would this be an accurate description of what is happening?

Comment: And therefore it would be accurate then to say that the `PartialFunction` in the implementation of `start` is what is closing over the current value of the `lst` parameter. I will reword the answer using further clarification from these comments.

Comment: Yes, the returned `PF` closes over `start`'s params. However, this is not the whole picture. That `PF` needs to be stored somewhere, and that somewhere is mutable.

Comment: Yes, it is only conceptually on the execution stack; as you point out the current behavior is *actually* held in mutable state internally. Using `become` may avoid mutable state in the actor code, but it doesn't avoid mutable state in the internal implementation.

Comment: So what's the benefit of using become / unbecome excepting the hot swap that I get?

Comment: Mutable state is inherent in the actor model, the creation of child actors is even mutable state. However, by keeping the mutable data out of the application code and isolated to the framework, it help ensure correctness of the application code. See also https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/5-actors.md#52-should-mutate-state-in-actors-only-with-contextbecome.

Comment: I found, especially, your last sentence to be helpful: `Only if you pass false for the discardOld parameter, allowing for a future unbecome, can there be an issue with a memory leak.`

Answer (score 1):

When using `become`/`unbecome` you are just changing the behavior of your actor not the state. State remains the same. However, when using it you can be leaking memory (take a look to this example for more detail: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-docs/rst/scala/code/docs/actor/UnnestedReceives.scala)

One more thing worth mentioning is that if you actor gets restarted by the supervisor, it will start with its original behavior.

`become/unbecome` is usually used either for initialization or a temporary change in state like for example flow control.

Comment: But where is the state in the second version. There is no var in the TestActor? After calling start 3 times with Add message, will the size of lst which is the parameter to the start method be 3?